# update insecure request on Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to look for a feature on ALB AWS that can update http to https on its own just like in the NGINX load balancer , currently I have a website that uses wordpress but when using ALB, the website only shows text , is there another way to `upgrade the url from http to https without having to edit the code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can **redirect http to https** as explained in AWS docs:

- [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/)

For that you need your **own domain name**. Once you have the domain you can the SSL certificate for HTTPS from Amazon Certificate Manager which you can deploy on your ALB.

Comment: sorry but it seems that I already know your answer , I want to upgrade the url from http to https , my website only opens port 80 http , on the ALB listener I created 2 ports of 80 and 443 , port 443 , port 443 uses ssl of aws , the main problem here is that my website has https but only displays text , I'm looking for a feature on ALB equivalent to upgrade-insecure-request like Nginx Webserver's

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngViệt There is no other way, except what I listed in the answer. If this is not suited, you have to look for a custom solution.